# How to get full url in Drupal 7

Tags: url, drupal

I'm using Drupal 7. I'm facing one issue. I want to get full url but my url is not clean. Here I'm sharing my url.

```
localhost/samplesite.com/sample-page.html?iniref=GOAI147600
```

Possible function what I'm using

```
request_uri(),
current_path(),
drupal_get_destination(),
url($_GET['q'], array('absolute' => TRUE),
$_SERVER();
```

the Output I get

```
localhost/samplesite.com/sample-page.html
```

but getting no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Im not using Drupal but you can url with $_SERVER.

```
$link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: Thanks @Nefro for your feedback. But I'm using this also but still getting nothing. Even in $_SERVER['Request_Uri'] it show blank.

Comment: Can you paste your .htaccess ?

Comment: I want to handle with init_hook

Comment: `request_uri()` is just a wrapper around `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` when not running from command line, so you should get also the query string (`?iniref=GOAI147600`). If that's not happening, are you sure that your code is called when it should? So, are you sure that the query string is not added in a redirect, on a page where your code is not being executed?